# Create object dynamically from string in Peoplecode

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I work on a Peoplesoft project and I am struggling with Peoplecode.
I want to create an object with a dynamic classname within Peoplecode. Kind of like in Java. This would look like something like this :

```
&my_object = create My_Application_Package : Class_string_name()
&my_object.commonMethodCall();
```

where "*Class_string_name*" would be dynamic. Is this possible ?
And do I mandatoraly need to create an interface for all the concerned classes ?

Any help or advise is welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is quite simple.

I just used CreateObject function :

> CreateObject(str_class_name, create_par, . . .)
>
> Where str_class_name either:
>
> —identifies a class by class name
>
> —identifies a class of OLE Automation object in the form:
>
> app_name.object_name
>
> Description
>
> Use the CreateObject function to return an instance of a class. You
>   can use this function to access an Application Class, a PeopleCode
>   built-in object (like a chart), or an OLE Automation object.
>
> If the class you are creating requires values to be passed, use the
>   create_par parameters to supply them, or use the CreateObjectArray
>   function.
>
> Considerations Using Application Classes
>
> You can use the CreateObject function to access an Application Class.
>   You would want to do this when you were programming at a high-level,
>   when you might not know the name of the class you wanted to access
>   until runtime. You must specify a fully-qualified class name. In
>   addition, the class name is case-sensitive.
>
> The returned object has the type of class you specified.

Comment: source for the quote: PeopleBooks > Enterprise People Tools 8.xx > PeopleCode Language Reference  > PeopleCode Built-in Functions https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcl/chapter.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm